# Beginner Issue - Unable to start without debugging on template "hello world" code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-debugging

I'm an absolute beginner and currently trying to follow the Lynda - Learning C# tutorial to start my coding journey.

Unfortunately I've run into trouble on the first task - to run the default template "hello world" code. I've double checked that i have installed Visual Studio 2019 as directed (.NET desktop development) and created the appropriate project template (Console App with .NET core). This then loads a template program identical to the lynda tutorial. See below:

VS19 Screen Cap

[image]

What I've noticed is the following:

1. Debug> Start Debugging/ Start without Debugging" are both greyed out
2. The green "play" button on the menu bar says "attach" rather than the project name as in the tutorial
3. In the solution explore panel - there are 0 projects whilst in the lynda tutorial the Hello World project appears with sub-menus of "dependencies" and "program.cs"

Appreciate any help!

Comment: If you start over  and follow the Microsoft tutorial, what do you get: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2022

Comment: I can't reproduce that however it is clear that you have your project separated from this solution. You can right click on solution 'Hello World' then 'Add...' and finally 'Project' then you should select where you have your "Project". It is where you have that program.cs.

Comment: Thanks for the responses

I followed the setting up a new project as @CaiusJard had suggested and get a similar condition as before 1)/ 2)/ 3) as mentioned in OP.

I also tried Dailosrs idea of right clicking on the "Solution "calculator" (0 projects)" in order to manually add / browse for the saved project. This brings up an error:  "project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate .NET SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.

Comment: So you started VS, went to "new project", picked "console app" and said OK, and you ended up with a screen that did have a program.cs open but solution explorer shows 0 projects. If you right click the program.cs tab and choose "open in explorer" does a disk window appear with other files like blahblah.csproj ?

Comment: Hmm, sounds like your install is damaged. I'd give a go at installing vs2019 - not much different but is fully released for years now/not in preview/only just released

Comment: Thats right @CaiusJard - i wonder if this is any issue with

1) Version of visual studio
2) Version of the .NET SDK (suggested by the above error)
3) Where im choosing to save the projects (desktop)

Comment: Im actually using 2019 - perhaps trying 2022 per the tutorial you suggested?

Comment: Project save location not so important. Vs installer should have installed an sdk; you can download separately if you want. Oh, yes. I'd got it into my head you were on 2022.. if you run the vs installer can you take a screenshot of what workflows you have ticked on (there's a screen where you pick what kind of dev you will do: web/python/xamarin/desktop etc) - in there you can pick components and I think the sdk should be one of the dependent components - does it say it's installed? Can also get it from here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: I'll try reinstalling then - i noticed i have .NET SDK 5.0.402 (x64) installed  - would one want to clear that too and do everything fresh ?

Comment: nevermind - it cannot be uninstalled independently and has done so when uninstalling VS19

Comment: @CaiusJard 

here is the cap of the installing configurations 

https://imgur.com/a/2Ql6HRm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your contributions - @CaiusJard @Dailosrs @AlexLeo

I'm not entirely sure what went wrong in my first installation of VS2019 as I had followed the tutorial exactly.

It seems that a fresh install of CS2022 has fixed the issue and the default code when opening the default template now both allows me to Start Debugging/ Start without Debugging and appears as a project in the Solution Explorer